# How to store a NumPy array as a key in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reinforcement-learning

I have a set of length three NumPy arrays. E.g.:

```
[ [0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2], [0,1,0],[0,1,1],... ]
```

For each of these NumPy arrays, I would like to store a list that is constantly being updated and have it in some way linked to a particular NumPy array.

For example, if for my NumPy array `[0,0,1]`, I had a corresponding list `[1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,1]`, how would I map the NumPy array to this list.

I have thought about using a dictionary, but Python does not seem to allow NumPy arrays to be used as keys within a dictionary.

Explicitly, I have 200 NumPy arrays which I am treating as states to a particular problem. These states are specified a three tuple, which I am using a NumPy array for. It is a requirement to my problem. Each of these states has a set of rewards, which I am currently using as a list.

I, therefore, need to link each state representation to a list of rewards for that state.

Any help would be great.

Comment: `dict` keys must be immutable. Numpy arrays are mutable. Ergo...

Comment: use the tuple equivalent as key

Answer (score 2):

As @chepner mentioned, you'll never be able to use numpy arrays as keys since they are mutable.  To solve your problem, you can try using a dictionary of dictionaries.  The format could be something a long the lines of this:

```
{'000': {state: [0,0,0], rewards: [1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,1]}, 
 '001': {state: [0,0,1], rewards: [1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,1]}, ...}
```

That way you can keep everything in the desired format, loop through it, and still have the states and rewards tied together.  Note that I chose the keys to be a string version of the state, but you could make that anything that makes sense for your particular problem.